# Split string with PHP

Tags: php, string, split

I have a number of ids that look like this:

```
100000584438452_522814274414716
1050090160_4191766746351
704475642_509010235785154
```

I need to split each up, and get the numbers after the _

I need to put the numbers after the _ in a variable $object_id.

Thanks

Comment: Use explode() and get last value of array

Comment: And have you actually tried anything yourself?

Comment: What is your current code? Where are you stuck?

Comment: let's vote to close this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string around the underscore and then set $object_id as the last value, like so:

```
$chunks = explode("_", $number_id);
$object_id = end($chunks);
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m sure that if you read this url http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php you´ll get it. There are even examples that can help you out.

Comment: There is no need to use `split` here. `explode` does the job fine.

Answer (score 0):

split() has been deprecated. try http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: It's true `split()` is deprecated but you're implying that explode is its replacement - which isn't true. Explode will get the job done but `preg_split()` should be used over `split()` http://php.net/preg_split

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayOfIds = explode("_", $yourIdsSeparatedByUnderscore);
$objectId = $arrayOfIds[1];
```